# Problems with NSTableView and NSArrayController

Tags: xcode, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

everybody! I'm a relative noob with xcode and objective-c. I'm trying to use an NSTableView with an NSArrayController to create a simple calculator. Not using core data, not using a document. When I try to run the app, I get the following message:

[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key payments.

I have beat my head against the wall, looked at several similar issues here on stackoverflow, and wasted several hours of time. The learning curve is now at zero, so I am punting this.

I have whittled down the project to bare bones and loaded it to https://github.com/boneoh/TableView

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Ok, I removed and re-added the NSArrayController and recreated the bindings. After that I changed the TableView to be cell-based instead of view-based. Still not sure why I was getting the original error = [valueForUndefinedKey].

Comment: FWIW, I believe NSMutableArray arrayWithArray returns an NSArray.  You need to use `mutableCopy` for what you want.  I do not quite see how that's your issue, though.

Comment: Aha. I have never run into it, but it may be that NSArrayController contentArray binding requires that your class either implement indexed accessors or mutableArrayValueForKey -- it's trying to mutate what it sees as an NSArray* property and it cannot find KVC methods that allow mutation.  See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSArrayController.html)